# Viewing PDF via Google docs viewer returns blank screen sometimes on Iphone

Tags: reactjs, safari, pdf-viewer, google-document-viewer

I am trying to show PDF documents, for safari browser users (iPhone/iPad) devices. So first i put **iframe** for previewing PDF on browser, that didn't helped at all, **iframe** was making PDF partial preview, like only one page of PDF was visible, no other pages were scroll able, So i took suggestion from some blog and tried to preview PDF documents via Google Docs Viewer, it was quite helpful, but some users reported issue of blank preview, So i tried to reproduce it, via reloading again and again, sometime its shows pretty good, but some of the times viewer doesnt show any page, just a blank preview comes. 
I need help to solve this problem, or any suggestions for PDF document viewer for iPhone/iPad safari users. Which will be best.
My application is built on react.js

Thank you in advance.

Comment: same issue , can you found any solution ?